# Yii2 dropdown empty option

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, yii2

How to implement the following Yii code to Yii2:

```
<?php 
   echo $form->dropDownList($model, 
                           'project', 
                           $model->getProjectOptions(), 
                           array('empty' => 'Empty string')
   ); 
?>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Why not

```
<?
    dropDownList($model, 
        'project', 
        $model->getProjectOptions(), 
        array('prompt'=>'Empty string')
    ); ?>
```

- prompt: string, a prompt text to be displayed as the first option;

Here is old CHtml https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/yii/helpers/base/Html.php

Can find there if you need something more.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#dropDownList()-detail Doc for Yii2 dropDownList

Comment: You can now set empty (prompt) options as of yii 2.0.11 as per [here in the docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#activeDropDownList()-detail)

Answer (score 11):

Use the following code to get the dropdownlist in yii2 friend.

```
<?php 
    //use app\models\Country;
    $countries=Country::find()->all();

    //use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
    $listData=ArrayHelper::map($countries,'code','name');

    echo $form->field($model, 'name')->dropDownList(
                                    $listData, 
                                    ['prompt'=>'Select...']);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this :
You can remove the templet if you want.

```
<?php
  $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'test-form',
    'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],
    'enableClientValidation'=> true,
    'enableAjaxValidation'=> false,
    'validateOnSubmit' => true,
    'validateOnChange' => true,
    'validateOnType' => true,
    'action' => Yii::$app->homeUrl . 'your/url/path'
  ]);
?>

    echo $form->field($model, 
                'your_field_name', 
                ['template' => '<div class="col-md-3">
                                     {label}
                                </div>
                               <div class="col-md-9"> 
                                     {input}{error}{hint}
                               </div>'
                ])
                ->dropdownList($option_array, ['prompt' => '--Select--']);

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking something like this?

```
<?=$form->field($model, 'project')
        ->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(['empty'=>'Empty string'], 'id', 'value'))
        ->label(false);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you make the projectOptions array, just make the first index had a null key, like that:

```
[
  null => 'Empty option',
  ... // Your options
]
```

And in your view you just add

```
$form->field($model, 'project')->dropDownList($model->projectOptions);
```

When your function name starts with 'get' followed by an uppercase letter, the yii understand that as an attribute, so

```
public function getSomeOptions(){ ..
```

is the same `someOptions`, is the same principle of the table relationships